# ping not recognized by powershell

Tags: powershell, ping

I am trying to run the ping command, yet I keep getting the error message "'ping' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

ping.exe exists within C:/Windows/System32.  The system path variable has C:/Windows/System32.  I still get that error when I go to the System32 directory to run ping.

Comment: did you close/re-open the console after adding to path? Also are you seeing the same issue when using cmd or only powershell?

Comment: Ok, after restarting console, it works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The native command in powershell is :

```
Test-Connection 127.0.0.1
```

By usually ping is an alis of this command, its strange ping 127.0.0.1 doesnt work.
Have you try to use complet pat of ping executable like this ?

```
C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE 127.0.0.1
```